# Working with args option of SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialog

Tags: 2010, asp.net, application-pages

I have the following situation: In my Sharepoint 2010 ASP.Net Application page app I want to allow my users to select a Supervisor for an employee who's information they (the user) is modifying. For various reasons I need to bring up a modal dialog box with a Telerik RadComboBox on it and two buttons: "submit" and "cancel." 
The normal course of processing is that they'd click the "Select Supervisor" button on the PARENT form which brings up my SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialog... Here's the code for that:

```
 function ShowDialog() {
    var origSupCN = document.getElementById('<%= txtSupervisorCN.ClientID %>').value;
    var origSup = document.getElementById('<%= txtSupervisor.ClientID %>').value;
    var args = {SupervisorCn: origSupCN, Supervisor: origSup};
    var _options = { title: "HR Employee Details",
        showClose: false,
        allowMaximize: false,
        width:400,
        height: 100,
        args: args
    };
    var rtvalue = SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogOpen("SupervisorDialog.aspx", _options, silentCallback);
}
```

Here's the rub: if the user clicks the "Select Supervisor" button to bring up that modal dialog box and then does NOT want to make a selection I need to return the value in the text box to it's original value. So I am passing in the original value in the "args" object - this is passed in to the ModalDialog and, if they click the "cancel" button on that Modal Dialog I want to set the return value to be what they passed in in the "args" object - but I don't know how to access those arg objects. Here's what I have so far:

```
function cancelForm() {
    var dialogResult = SP.UI.DialogResult.OK;

    var returnValue = Array();
    returnValue[0] = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args("SupervisorCn");  //comboItem.get_value();   //SupervisorCN
    returnValue[1] = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args("Supervisor"); //"No Supervisor Selected";  //comboItem.get_text();     //Supervisor;
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(dialogResult, returnValue);
}
```

This is called when the user, on the Modal Dialog box, clicks the "cancel" button - I am attempting to set the return value to the original values passed into the creation of the Modal Dialog box... wow, I'm not sure if this makes a lick of sense at this point... I hope it does.

Basically I am passing in an args object to ModalDialog and want to GET those values from w/in a JavaScript method if the user clicks the "cancel" button so I can set the return value to the original value passed in... that's it in a nutshell. But I don't know how to refer to the "args" object when I'm in JavaScript in my Modal Dialog...

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

To access the args object on the Modal Dialog,  you will have to write some JavaScript code in the `SupervisorDialog.aspx` which you open inside the dialog.

You will have to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getArgsInPage, "sp.js");

function getArgsInPage(){
    var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
}
</script>
```

on the `SupervisorDialog.aspx` to get the `args` object.

See this link for more details:
http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/11/17/using-the-dialog-framework-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply. Still coming back as "undefined" however.

Comment: This only seems to work partially.  Sometimes I get results, usually undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these options work some of the time but inconsistently:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetArgs);
//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetArgs, "sp.js");

function GetArgs(){
    var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
};
```

This has been working consistently everytime on Chrome and IE11:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetArgs);

function GetArgs(){
        var args = window.frameElement.dialogArgs;
        //var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
};
```

Hat Tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970048/how-to-get-args-from-sp-ui-modaldialog